# Programmatically Capture Maximum Resolution Image using AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, avfoundation

My goal is to use an `AVCaptureSession` to programmatically lock focus, capture one image, activate the flash, then capture a second image after some delay.

I have managed to get the captures to work using an `AVCaptureSession` instance and an `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`. However, the images I get when calling `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(_:completionHandler:)` are 1920 x 1080, not the full 12 megapixel image my iPhone 6S camera is capable of.

Here is my capture function:

```
func captureImageFromStream(completion: (result: UIImage) -> Void)
{
    if let stillOutput = self.stillImageOutput {
        var videoConnection : AVCaptureConnection?
        for connection in stillOutput.connections {
            for port in connection.inputPorts! {
                if port.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo {
                    videoConnection = connection as? AVCaptureConnection
                    break
                }
            }
            if videoConnection != nil {
                break
            }
        }
        if videoConnection != nil {
            stillOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
                (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)

                    if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        completion(result: image)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    NSLog("ImageCapture Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What modifications should I make to capture the image I'm looking for? I'm new to Swift, so please excuse any beginner mistakes I've made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you `addOutput` the `stillImageOutput` and `startRunning`, you need to set your capture session preset to photo:

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks.